# Filename displays with ? char when `ls` while with junk character when `ls | grep fran`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs, unicode, character-encoding

What is the configuration that defines how file name with unrecognizable character be replaced with some other character. For example in my Linux system same file is displayed differently  in UTF8 environment setting in PuTTY

```
$ ls | grep fran
fran▒aise

$ ls
fran?aise
```

`fran▒aise` -> its encoded byte is `fran\xe2\x96\x92aise`

I guess system is doing all this because it is not understanding latin encoded `\xe7` byte

Also when I copy in another folder which is basically a different NFS mount then it displays with different name: `fran栩se`.

How can I check the configuration that does all this implicit changes?

```
locale:
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What's your locale set to?

Comment: @Kusalananda it is default I have pasted above

Answer (score 0):

in putty I use

Configuration -> Windows -> Translation -> Remote character set : UTF-8

in linux

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

all works fine

```
Linux > echo élève > française
Linux > od -c française
0000000 303 251   l 303 250   v   e  \n
0000010
Linux > ls | od -c
0000000   f   r   a   n 303 247   a   i   s   e  \n
0000013
Linux > ls
française
```

and full `stty`

```
Linux > stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 129; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

when scp'ing from windows to linux a file named `vérification.xml`

in dos

```
vÚrification.xml          | 99 kB |  99.9 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

in linux

```
Linux > LANG=C.utf8 ls
fran??aise  v?rification.xml
Linux > LANG=POSIX ls
fran??aise  v?rification.xml
Linux > LANG=french ls
française  v▒rification.xml
Linux > LANG=fr_FR.iso88591 ls
française  v▒rification.xml
Linux > LANG=fr_FR.utf8 ls
française  v?rification.xml
```